# how to get nested master-detail or master - detail -detail query in Loopback

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, loopbackjs, loopback

I have `category` and `category_subs`, master-detail model, post model `belongs to` category_subs. In the following code, I can get master-detail of both but I don't know how to include `post` to them or even `attachment` model of the post to the remote method.

```
module.exports = function (Category) {
    Category.categorySubs = function (id, cb) {
    Category.find({
        where: {
          id: id
        },    
        include: {
            relation: 'categorySubs',
          scope: {
              include: 'category_subs'
          }
        }
      },
      function (err, posts) {
        cb(null, posts);
      });
  }
 Category.remoteMethod('categorySubs', {
    accepts: {
      arg: 'id',
      type: 'string'
    },
    returns: {
      arg: 'ID',
      type: 'string'
    },
    http: {
      path: '/iteminfo',
      verb: 'get'
    }
  });
```

**update**

**category.json**

```
"relations": {
    "categorySubs": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "category_subs",
      "foreignKey": "catgory_id"
    }
  },
```

**category_subs**

```
"relations": {
    "posts": {
      "type": "hasMany",
      "model": "post",
      "foreignKey": "category_sub_id"
    }
  },
```

Comment: could you add  related models relations to question body?

Answer (score 1):

I googled and I think you had to have deep look at https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Include-filter.html